# GA4 shows different Total Users from Country to Region to Town/City

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

GA4 or Google Analytics 4 shows different total users when you switch your dimension from Country to Region to City.

This is in all the accounts that I've checked.

I do not see any explanation to this varying user count in official documentation.

I'm pasting screenshots from the Google's Official Demo Account Property Merch Shop

[image]

Hoping someone can explain this discrepency.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may split the first Country report by Region by clicking the "+" sign and adding Region column to the report. The new report would have to columns: [Country and Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEc6c.png). Should have the same number of Users as the first Country report.

Comment: No, it reduces the number of users the moment you add region as secondary dimension.